Should questions about GeoPandas regarding controversial borders be flagged?
Say someone might ask about GeoPandas regarding the borders of China, Israel, Tibet or other borders that are subjects of controversial political discussions. Should a hypothetical question about this be flagged due to rudeness?
An example would be "I want to include Taiwan in my China GeoPandas. How can I do that?"

Is it a programming question? For example something like "Geopandas gives me following output: ... for country A I want it to give this output as per XYZ source, how do I do that?"

This seems to match "Needs improvement" => "A community-specific reason" => "Not about programming or software development" to a T, unless of course it is about a programming problem in which case it would be fine. Why do you think this warrants any special treatment?

If the question is an on-topic programming question, what geographical location it is about is irrelevant; the question is about the programming not the location. Would you flag a question because it had a variable with the value 'Russia' or an Object named ChinaTown?

While this is perhaps an unlikely hypothetical, it is a hypothetical about Stack Overflow, so it appears to me to be on-topic on Meta Stack Overflow.

Questions asked on Stack Overflow are about:


a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development


If Geopandas is a tool used by programmers and a question about borders is a specific programming problem unique to software development then the question is on-topic.
It doesn't matter whether these borderlines are for contested areas or not. Programmers aren't politicians. Programmers don't solve controversies unless it is between competing pip packages. Programmers don't care where their end-users want the borderlines drawn. The technical solution doesn't change depending on which side of the aisle you personally are.
Maps in software anger the world, since forever: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UCohRKY2ns
If questions contain noise or irrelevant opinions for the task at hand about these borderlines, edit the question to make the content to the point. If those noise-reduction edits gets reverted, flag for a moderator. Mentioning Taiwan and China by itself isn't noise, added (dis-)qualifications are.
I don't think that a question that asks about how to combine two distinct landmasses as one where the two landmasses are specifically named for context is a Code Of Conduct violation, not even in the Harmful political content policy category. Assume good faith until proven otherwise.

It might certainly be marked a duplicate of a more general question, such as how to union polygons in geopandas, as country borders are often represented by polygons (I'm not experienced in geopandas but in the GISes I worked with there was nothing specific about a country border).

Some programmers absolutely do care about how country borders are drawn by software they create. Programmers, say, who are subject to a code of ethics and are required to reduce harm and recognize that insisting on using certain borders in an application may cause harm. This doesn't make consideration on topic,  though.
